# Replace script works if I type manually but not in script

Tags: bash, shell, ack

I have a bash script, replace.sh with the following contents:

```
ack-grep -a -l -i --print0 --text "$1" | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/$1/$2/g'
```

When I try and run it as, eg:

replace.sh something somethingnew

The prompt returns without errors but no changes have been made to any files.
If I manually type:

```
ack-grep -a -l -i --print0 --text "something" | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/something/somethingelse/g'
```

The files get changed as expected.

Ths $1 syntax seems to work for other scripts I've written.  I'm guessing I'm missing something to do with escaping the args or something?

Thanks!

Ludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable substitutions aren't done in single quotes, try:

```
ack-grep -a -l -i --print0 --text "$1" | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e "s/$1/$2/g"
```

See the bash man page section on QUOTING.

Answer (score 1):

Use `""` instead of `''` in the sed expression. It will not prevent the variablename-resolving. What you are actually doing now is replacing `$1` to `$2`. You can test in console (without writing a script) like this:

```
$ a=something

$ b=somethingelse

$ sed 's/$a/$b/g' testfile

$ sed "s/$a/$b/g" testfile
```

Comment: Thanks! :) 2 x correct answers, both at the same time, but gave the answer to the other bloke as it was his first answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to your question, but some help on using ack.

The `-a` and `--text` conflict with each other.  `-a` will give you a superset of `--text`.  Use one or the other.

Also, it looks like you might as well use `grep -Z` instead of ack since you're not using any of ack's functionality that is a superset of grep.

In general, if you're using ack in a pipeline, you should probably be using good ol' grep instead.